# Is there Japanese audio for "The Daily Life of the Immortal King"?

Tags: the-daily-life-of-the-immortal-king

I tried to watch it and the audio isn’t Japanese and I would prefer to watch it with Japanese audio and English subtitles or English audio. Do any of these exist and if so where can I watch them?

Comment: Note to answerers: take note that this site doesn't condone piracy, so links to questionable sites will be deleted without prompt. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I know that there isn't a dub in English, but I doubt there will be one in Japanese either.

It also hit me pretty hard when I realised it wasn't Japanese in the first 20 seconds of it, but honestly? I've been putting off learning Mandarin for so long and this just made me finally commit.

It's unique. It's different. Just enjoy it the way it's supposed to be.

Comment: Crunchyroll has some of it in English now

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe so because it is produced by Bilibili. They often don't have their anime in Japanese dub or English dub.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked in the body of your question whether English audio is available, an English dub for the first season of the anime is now available at [Crunchyroll](https://www.crunchyroll.com/series/GZJH3DJ8E/the-daily-life-of-the-immortal-king). (User [Joe W](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/62365/is-there-japanese-audio-for-the-daily-life-of-the-immortal-king#comment80005_64146) also mentioned this in a comment under another answer.)

Some information regarding the English cast, etc. can be found at the [Anime News Network](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=25443).